# Freemarker - Defining custom build-ins / filters

Tags: freemarker

Is it possible to define a custom [build-ins](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html) (name no longer will be suitable) in ftl?
I don't want to make it a function but instead a build-in, because of semantic premises.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible, the `?` syntax is reserved for the built-in functions. (This meant to change in the future BTW. Sadly, in the far future, judging from the size of the backlog before it and the pace it's eliminated...)

Comment: could you provide some link ?

Comment: for the backlog with ticket for this. Nevermind, still deserves an upvote ;-)

Answer (score 2):

For the completeness, here is [Daniel's (@ddekany's) old response](http://freemarker.624813.n4.nabble.com/How-to-add-custom-method-using-built-in-like-syntax-td3081132.html). I think not much changed since 2010 and 2013 in this field :)

---

No, the `?something` syntax is reserved for core functions to avoid name 
clashes when new core functions are added. You can do 
`${translate_into_swahili(mytext)}` however. For that, depending on your 
application, do one of these:

- Create a template that defines your function(s) then include 
  `#include` or `#import` that in your normal templates. Note that 
  functions can be implemented in pure FreeMarker with `#function`, or 
  in Java as `TemplateMethodModelEx`-s and then where you would use

  ```
  <#function foo>...</#function> use 
  <#assign foo=your.class.Name"?new()> instead.
  ```
- Implement the function in Java as `TemplateMethodModelEx`, and the put 
  it into the data-model
- Implement the function in Java as `TemplateMethodModelEx`, and then 
  make it available on the single spot where you initialize `FreeMarker` with 
  `Configuration.setSharedVariable(name, method)`

Comment: I appreciate the copy of the older response here. I'm surprised that Freemarker doesn't support custom built-ins. Many template engines have the concept of "filters" for formatting and custom formatting is often necessary. I'm using Freemarker for code generation rather than for displaying a web page. So, this becomes more important in my case.